# Ruby, array with same values and different index number

Tags: arrays, ruby

If we have an array with some duplicate values, how do we give different index numbers to these values? E.g., we have `array = ["a", "b", "c", "b", "e", "b", "d"]`. The index of the array is

`0
1
2
1
3
1
4`

How do we convert the index to:

`0
1
2
3
4
5
6`

Comment: Not clear what you mean.

Comment: How about `array.sort`? Does that do what you want?

Comment: No, sort is just for sorting the index. if you check the indexes above, you will see that all the duplicated values have the same index number. I don't want that. I want the duplicate values to have different index numbers.

Comment: @sawa I think the question is clear. Keep the duplicate values with different index numbers.

Comment: An array's indexes will always be strictly ascending, i.e. 0, 1, 2, 3, etc., regardless of whether or not it has duplicate values.

Comment: @Jordan try this:`def add(*args)
 
 $i =[]
 for x in args
 puts args.index(x)
 
 end
end

add(8, 2, 6, 6, -6, -11, 6, 4, -4, -17, -17, -8, -10, 11, 20, 10, 4)'

Comment: or this `def add(*args)

 $i =[]
 for x in args
  $i << (x) * (args.index(x)+(1))
  
 end
 
 $i.each do |x|
     puts $i.index(x)
 end
 
end

add(8, 2, 6, 6, -6, -11, 6, 4, -4, -17, -17, -8, -10, 11, 20, 10, 4)`

Comment: `Array#index` returns the index of the *first* matching element. The index of the first 6 is `2` and the index of the second 6 is `3`, but the `index` method has no way of knowing that you want the first, second, or third 6. When you do `args.index(6)` it will always return the index of the first 6 it finds—it doesn't mean the other 6es have the same index.

Comment: Student: "Teach, I've got a question: ej%c.s()". Teacher: "I don't understand your question". Student: "I think my question is clear."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably misunderstood the `array.index(object)` method. It gives always the index of first occurrence. ie always index of first duplicate element. see more details [Array index method](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-index).

As per the code you given in comments, you are using

```
 def add(*args)
   $i =[]
   for x in args
     puts args.index(x)
   end
 end 
 add(8, 2, 6, 6, -6, -11, 6, 4, -4, -17, -17, -8, -10, 11, 20, 10, 4)
```

`args.index(x)` will always return the first occurrence of element in the array.

Comment: thanks a lot. Really brain breaking.

Answer (score 1):

**FYI:** Array index always in ascending order started from `0` even array contains duplicate value. And as per your expected output your array has index from `0` to `6` only.

```
> array = ["a", "b", "c", "b", "e", "b", "d"]
#=> ["a", "b", "c", "b", "e", "b", "d"] 
> array.each_with_index{|e,i| p "#{e} at index => #{i}"}
# "a at index => 0"
# "b at index => 1"
# "c at index => 2"
# "b at index => 3"
# "e at index => 4"
# "b at index => 5"
# "d at index => 6"
```

Even this will return the same output:

```
> array.each_with_index{|e,i| p "#{array[i]} at index => #{i}"}
```

Comment: But each_with_index, just enumerates the values of the array, doesn't return the indexes of the values. just try the above examples.

Comment: @kosmas : it returns the index as second argument in block, here in my code `i` is for `index` and `e` for `value`. Please refer http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_with_index

Comment: @kosmas : `array.each_with_index{|e,i| p "#{array[i]} at index => #{i}"}` will return the same output